# How can I send with 'struct.pack' type over Modbus TCP?

Tags: python, tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp

I want to send packet over Modbus TCP. I want to use:

But I can not send this way how can I send this packet? (I don't know something will be)

```
req = struct.pack(
   'Something', transaction, identifier, length, unitid, func_code, reg_addr
)
```

These are my variables:

```
transaction=0x01
identifier=0x00
length=[0x00,0x06]
unitid=0x01
func_code=0x03
reg_addr=[0x13,0x14,0x15]
```

Comment: Why you don't use the [pymodbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) library?

Comment: Also `struct.pack` not support a list as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At first you can use [pymodbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) library with very features.
- Also `struct.pack()` not support a list as argument.
- `0001 0000 0006 11 03 006B 0003` is a standard example of Modbus-TCP packet which contained:

> `0001: Transaction Identifier`
>
> `0000: Protocol Identifier`
>
> `0006: Message Length (6 bytes to follow)`
>
> `11: The Unit Identifier  (17 = 11 hex)`
>
> `03: The Function Code (read Analog Output Holding Registers)`
>
> `006B: The Data Address of the first register requested. (40108-40001 = 107 =6B hex)`
>
> `0003: The total number of registers requested. (read 3 registers 40108 to 40110)`
>
> <sub>[Reference](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/TCP.htm)</sub>

Thus, you can create a *Modbus-TCP* packet with the above example:

```
import struct

transaction = 0x0001
identifier = 0x0000
length = 0x0006
unitid = 0x11
fcode = 0x03  # Holding register fcode.
reg_addr = 0x006B  # Register address.
count = 0x0003  # Read three register.


total_pack_string = '0x{:04x}{:04x}{:04x}{:02x}{:02x}{:04x}{:04x}'.format(
    transaction, identifier, length, unitid, fcode, reg_addr, count
)
total_pack_hex = hex(int(total_pack_string, 16))

'''Or with using pack method.'''
pack_ = struct.pack(
   '>HHHBBHH', transaction, identifier, length, unitid, fcode, reg_addr, count
)

# Then send the pack_ or total_pack_hex using a TCP-Socket.
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `transaction` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `identifier` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `length` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `unitid` is 1Byte == `B`
- `fcode` is 1Byte == `B`
- `reg_addr` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `count` is 2Byte == Short == `H`
- `B` is `unsigned byte`
- `H` is `unsigned short`

Thus, the format will be like this `>HHHBBHH`

---

### Using [pymodbus](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus) equivalent:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

unitid = 0x11
fcode = 0x03  # Holding register fcode.
reg_addr = 0x006B  # Register address.
count = 0x0003  # Read three register.

cli = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1', port=502)

if cli.connect():
    res = cli.read_holding_registers(reg_addr, count=count, unit=unitid)
    
    if not res.isError():
        print(res.registers)
    else:
        print('There is an error.')
    cli.close()
else:
    print('Error in connection.')
```

Comment: It is a wonderfull answer. Thank you. (I dont want to use pymodbus library so i am trying without pymodbus)